# Sending geo URI by hyperlink in Gmail not working

Tags: android, android-intent, hyperlink, gmail, gis

I'm trying to send an email with a GEO URI to an Android phone however when I open the email in Android's Gmail app, it loses the hyperlink functionality.

I need this link so that I can open the coordinates in an offline maps app like OSMand which will capture the intent but it needs that hyperlink functionality first. Here's what the code looks like:

```
<a href="geo:37.786971,-122.399677;u=35">Wikimedia Headquarters</a>
```

Suggestions?

Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geo_URI

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Gmail strips out the geo URI among others.  Accessing the Gmail account by IMAP or POP in Android's regular email client retains the URI.